# How to create a custom table and provide a Create,Read,Update,Delete interface

Tags: abap

How will I create a new structure in the ABAP dictionary has the following attributes.
Name Type,MyNAME CHAR(25),FatherNAME CHAR(25),DEGREE CHAR(25),AGE INT4,BIRTHDAY DATS
 and write a ABAP program that will use your created structure, fill in all of the information on the structure & write it out to the screen

Answer (score 2):

This requires no coding at all.

Just create the table ( use transaction SE11 ), then run the table generator ( you will find it in the menu in SE11 ). Then run SM30, fill in your table and hit display or maintain.

You can make then a parameter transaction that pre-fills the initial SM30 screen, this requires no coding as well.